# What is required for a question/answer to contain "enough information"?

Tags: discussion

I'm re-purposing this question I was helpfully redirected to by my Mod peers, for the use of Poker.SE.

There are questions/answers on this site that are requesting/recommending software and I suspect that they may well become a target for spam. That said, answered well like what you might find on [SoftwareRecs.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) using their [well received guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336), they could provide great advice for players to make informed decisions.

This is an attempt to gather feedback about the answers already in existence and how to treat them and future ones. For example:

Q - [The state of the art of the pokerbots of poker academy](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/988/88)
Q - [Can anyone suggest a limit holdem training app for Android?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/6341/88)
Q - [Poker Academy Pro or an alternative](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/765/88)

These three Q's all have answers that provide little content other than a link to a piece of software. The question being **What is the acceptable standard for an answer about a recommendation for this site?**

This isn't limited to software, but should definitely include it.

The community should guide this decision.

Comment: FYI, if you don't see examples on the referenced Q's it's because I have deleted the repeat offenders for the reason of "Spamming" an answer with a simple link.